# How should I deal with mutexes in movable types in C++?

Tags: c++, mutex, move-constructor

By design, `std::mutex` is not movable nor copyable. This means that a class `A` holding a mutex won't receive a default move constructor.

How would I make this type `A` movable in a thread-safe way?

Comment: Why would you want to, in the first place?

Comment: Mutex would usually be method scoped

Comment: The question has a quirk: Shall the move operation itself also be thread-safe, or is it sufficient if other accesses to the object are thread safe?

Comment: @paulm That really depends on the design. I have often seen a class have a mutex member variable, then only the `std::lock_guard` is method scoped.

Comment: @Anton Savin: I can think of many use cases.. one example would be a "lockable"-base class, which shouldn't limit the derived class movability.

Comment: @Jonas Wielicki: At first I thought moveing it should also be thread-safe. However, not that I think about it again, this doesn't make much sense, since move-constructing an object usually invalidates the state of the old-object. So other threads *mustn't* be able to access the old-object, if it's going to be moved.. otherwise they might soon access an invalid object. Am I right?

Comment: I think, your idea is wrong. You should not have a class having a mutex, but an external mutex protecting the class.

Comment: please follow this link may use full for it https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/thread-safe-copy-constructors.html

Comment: @Dieter Lücking: yeah, this is the idea.. mutex M protects class B. However, where do I store both to have a thread-safe, accessible object? Both M and B might go to class A.. and in this case class A would have a Mutex at class scope.

Comment: @jack mutexes do not make code thread safe.  They do not protect against deadlocks.  Having each object have its own mutex just means your threading problems appear later in the design cycle, when everything is tangled in knots, and you have hard coded the "thread safety".  If a particular object need be thread safe, it means it is shared.  Shared objects should be rare, and it should not involve modifying their class heirarchy.  Try a thread-safety wrapper?  The fact you are asking "how do I move" without a "I need to move" scenario highlights the problem with your design.

Comment: I don't think having a mutex as a class member is a bad thing in certain circumstances. Imagine a IOManager class which has a vector of ReadRequests. If the IOManager is to be thread safe you'd want a mutex protecting those requests. You could have a global/static mutex but then different instances of an IOManager would interfere with each other. You could make the IOManager global or a singleton but these each have their well know issues. We generally just use a `shared_ptr<IOManager>` or `unique_ptr<IOManager>` to avoid these issues.

Comment: Mutex, almost by definition, needs to be shared, because if several threads aren't accessing it at the same time, why do you even have it? And what would it mean, to move a mutex in one thread, while it is waiting to acquire lock in another thread? So simple answer is, don't move the mutex, just move a shared pointer pointing to a separate mutex object. I think you should really add some example code or more detailed scenario to the question, esp. now that it has gotten all these upvotes.

Comment: To everyone saying "classes shouldn't have a mutex": Tell that to the C++ standards committee. Because [std::shared_ptr has a mutex](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a01031_source.html). Going nuclear and saying "a class should never have a mutex member" is going too far: most classes shouldn't have a mutex member, but some might actually need it.

Comment: @Cornstalks the internal class that `std::shared_ptr` manages has a `mutex`.  That internal class is not exposed and not copied nor moved.  It exists purely in a class with a narrow responsibility.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Let's start with a bit of code:

```
class A
{
    using MutexType = std::mutex;
    using ReadLock = std::unique_lock<MutexType>;
    using WriteLock = std::unique_lock<MutexType>;

    mutable MutexType mut_;

    std::string field1_;
    std::string field2_;

public:
    ...
```

I've put some rather suggestive type aliases in there that we won't really take advantage of in C++11, but become much more useful in C++14.  Be patient, we'll get there.

Your question boils down to:

> How do I write the move constructor and move assignment operator for this class?

We'll start with the move constructor.

**Move Constructor**

Note that the member `mutex` has been made `mutable`.  Strictly speaking this isn't necessary for the move members, but I'm assuming you also want copy members.  If that is not the case, there is no need to make the mutex `mutable`.

When constructing `A`, you do not need to lock `this->mut_`.  But you do need to lock the `mut_` of the object you're constructing from (move or copy).  This can be done like so:

```
    A(A&& a)
    {
        WriteLock rhs_lk(a.mut_);
        field1_ = std::move(a.field1_);
        field2_ = std::move(a.field2_);
    }
```

Note that we had to default construct the members of `this` first, and then assign them values only after `a.mut_` is locked.

**Move Assignment**

The move assignment operator is substantially more complicated because you do not know if some other thread is accessing either the lhs or rhs of the assignment expression.  And in general, you need to guard against the following scenario:

```
// Thread 1
x = std::move(y);

// Thread 2
y = std::move(x);
```

Here is the move assignment operator that correctly guards the above scenario:

```
    A& operator=(A&& a)
    {
        if (this != &a)
        {
            WriteLock lhs_lk(mut_, std::defer_lock);
            WriteLock rhs_lk(a.mut_, std::defer_lock);
            std::lock(lhs_lk, rhs_lk);
            field1_ = std::move(a.field1_);
            field2_ = std::move(a.field2_);
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

Note that one must use `std::lock(m1, m2)` to lock the two mutexes, instead of just locking them one after the other.  If you lock them one after the other, then when two threads assign two objects in opposite order as shown above, you can get a deadlock.  The point of `std::lock` is to avoid that deadlock.

**Copy Constructor**

You didn't ask about the copy members, but we might as well talk about them now (if not you, somebody will need them).

```
    A(const A& a)
    {
        ReadLock  rhs_lk(a.mut_);
        field1_ = a.field1_;
        field2_ = a.field2_;
    }
```

The copy constructor looks much like the move constructor except the `ReadLock` alias is used instead of the `WriteLock`.  Currently these both alias `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` and so it doesn't really make any difference.

But in C++14, you will have the option of saying this:

```
    using MutexType = std::shared_timed_mutex;
    using ReadLock  = std::shared_lock<MutexType>;
    using WriteLock = std::unique_lock<MutexType>;
```

This *may* be an optimization, but not definitely.  You will have to measure to determine if it is.  But with this change, one can copy construct **from** the same rhs in multiple threads simultaneously.  The C++11 solution forces you to make such threads sequential, even though the rhs isn't being modified.

**Copy Assignment**

For completeness, here is the copy assignment operator, which should be fairly self explanatory after reading about everything else:

```
    A& operator=(const A& a)
    {
        if (this != &a)
        {
            WriteLock lhs_lk(mut_, std::defer_lock);
            ReadLock  rhs_lk(a.mut_, std::defer_lock);
            std::lock(lhs_lk, rhs_lk);
            field1_ = a.field1_;
            field2_ = a.field2_;
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

**And etc.**

Any other members or free functions that access `A`'s state will also need to be protected if you expect multiple threads to be able to call them at once.  For example, here's `swap`:

```
    friend void swap(A& x, A& y)
    {
        if (&x != &y)
        {
            WriteLock lhs_lk(x.mut_, std::defer_lock);
            WriteLock rhs_lk(y.mut_, std::defer_lock);
            std::lock(lhs_lk, rhs_lk);
            using std::swap;
            swap(x.field1_, y.field1_);
            swap(x.field2_, y.field2_);
        }
    }
```

Note that if you just depend on `std::swap` doing the job, the locking will be at the wrong granularity, locking and unlocking between the three moves that `std::swap` would internally perform.

Indeed, thinking about `swap` can give you insight into the API you might need to provide for a "thread-safe" `A`, which in general will be different from a "non-thread-safe" API, because of the "locking granularity" issue.

Also note the need to protect against "self-swap".  "self-swap" should be a no-op.  Without the self-check one would recursively lock the same mutex.  This could also be solved without the self-check by using `std::recursive_mutex` for `MutexType`.

**Update**

In the comments below Yakk is pretty unhappy about having to default construct things in the copy and move constructors (and he has a point).  Should you feel strongly enough about this issue, so much so that you are willing to spend memory on it, you can avoid it like so:

- Add whatever lock types you need as data members.  These members must come before the data that is being protected:

  ```
  mutable MutexType mut_;
  ReadLock  read_lock_;
  WriteLock write_lock_;
  // ... other data members ...
  ```
- And then in the constructors (e.g. the copy constructor) do this:

  ```
  A(const A& a)
      : read_lock_(a.mut_)
      , field1_(a.field1_)
      , field2_(a.field2_)
  {
      read_lock_.unlock();
  }
  ```

Oops, Yakk erased his comment before I had the chance to complete this update.  But he deserves credit for pushing this issue, and getting a solution into this answer.

**Update 2**

And dyp came up with this good suggestion:

```
    A(const A& a)
        : A(a, ReadLock(a.mut_))
    {}
private:
    A(const A& a, ReadLock rhs_lk)
        : field1_(a.field1_)
        , field2_(a.field2_)
    {}
```

Comment: Your copy constructor assigns fields, it doesn't copy them.  That means they need be default-constructable, which is an unfortunate restriction.

Comment: @Yakk:  Yes, putting `mutexes` into class types isn't the "one true way".  It is a tool in the toolbox and if you want to use it, this is how.

Comment: @Yakk:  Search my answer for the string "C++14".

Comment: ah, sorry, I missed that C++14 bit.

Comment: great explanation @HowardHinnant! in C++17 you can also use std::scoped_lock lock(x.mut_, y_mut_); That way you rely on the implementation to lock several mutexes in a proper order

Comment: great answer, looks good. With respect to the move semantics you've illustrated here, how is construction/destruction of the mutices dealt with? In your move ctor, I assume that one would construct `this.mut_` in the initializer list, but then what happens to `a.mut_'?

Comment: `this.mut_` can be implicitly default constructed.  Though if you feel strongly about it, explicitly default constructing it in the initializer list is also ok.  `a.mut_` is already default constructed by one of `a`'s constructors.  One only needs to lock it so it is safe to copy from the members it is protecting.

Comment: Would I run into problems if I derived from `A` and say, added another member `std::string field3_`?

Comment: I'm not seeing any problems with that, but admittedly I haven't coded it up and poked at it.

Answer (score 12):

Given there doesn't seem to be a nice, clean, easy way to answer this - Anton's solution I *think* is correct but its definitely debatable, unless a better answer comes up I would recommend putting such a class on the heap and looking after it via a `std::unique_ptr`:

```
auto a = std::make_unique<A>();
```

Its now a fully movable type and anyone who has a lock on the internal mutex whilst a move happens is still safe, even if its debatable whether this is a good thing to do

If you need copy semantics just use

```
auto a2 = std::make_shared<A>();
```

Answer (score 7):

This is an upside-down answer.  Instead of embedding "this objects needs to be synchronized" as a base of the type, instead inject it *under* any type.

You deal with a synchronized object very differently.  One big issue is you have to worry about deadlocks (locking multiple objects).  It also should basically never be your "default version of an object": synchronized objects are for objects that will be in contention, and your goal should be to minimize contention between threads, not sweep it under the rug.

But synchronizing objects is still useful.  Instead of inheriting from a synchronizer, we can write a class that wraps an arbitrary type in synchronization.  Users have to jump through a few hoops to do operations on the object now that it is synchronized, but they are not limited to some hand-coded limited set of operations on the object.  They can compose multiple operations on the object into one, or have an operation on multiple objects.

Here is a synchronized wrapper around an arbitrary type `T`:

```
template<class T>
struct synchronized {
  template<class F>
  auto read(F&& f) const&->std::result_of_t<F(T const&)> {
    return access(std::forward<F>(f), *this);
  }
  template<class F>
  auto read(F&& f) &&->std::result_of_t<F(T&&)> {
    return access(std::forward<F>(f), std::move(*this));
  }
  template<class F>
  auto write(F&& f)->std::result_of_t<F(T&)> {
    return access(std::forward<F>(f), *this);
  }
  // uses `const` ness of Syncs to determine access:
  template<class F, class... Syncs>
  friend auto access( F&& f, Syncs&&... syncs )->
  std::result_of_t< F(decltype(std::forward<Syncs>(syncs).t)...) >
  {
    return access2( std::index_sequence_for<Syncs...>{}, std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Syncs>(syncs)... );
  };
  synchronized(synchronized const& o):t(o.read([](T const&o){return o;})){}
  synchronized(synchronized && o):t(std::move(o).read([](T&&o){return std::move(o);})){}  
  // special member functions:
  synchronized( T & o ):t(o) {}
  synchronized( T const& o ):t(o) {}
  synchronized( T && o ):t(std::move(o)) {}
  synchronized( T const&& o ):t(std::move(o)) {}
  synchronized& operator=(T const& o) {
    write([&](T& t){
      t=o;
    });
    return *this;
  }
  synchronized& operator=(T && o) {
    write([&](T& t){
      t=std::move(o);
    });
    return *this;
  }
private:
  template<class X, class S>
  static auto smart_lock(S const& s) {
    return std::shared_lock< std::shared_timed_mutex >(s.m, X{});
  }
  template<class X, class S>
  static auto smart_lock(S& s) {
    return std::unique_lock< std::shared_timed_mutex >(s.m, X{});
  }
  template<class L>
  static void lock(L& lockable) {
      lockable.lock();
  }
  template<class...Ls>
  static void lock(Ls&... lockable) {
      std::lock( lockable... );
  }
  template<size_t...Is, class F, class...Syncs>
  friend auto access2( std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&&f, Syncs&&...syncs)->
  std::result_of_t< F(decltype(std::forward<Syncs>(syncs).t)...) >
  {
    auto locks = std::make_tuple( smart_lock<std::defer_lock_t>(syncs)... );
    lock( std::get<Is>(locks)... );
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Syncs>(syncs).t ...);
  }

  mutable std::shared_timed_mutex m;
  T t;
};
template<class T>
synchronized< T > sync( T&& t ) {
  return {std::forward<T>(t)};
}
```

C++14 and C++1z features included.

this assumes that `const` operations are multiple-reader safe (which is what `std` containers assume).

Use looks like:

```
synchronized<int> x = 7;
x.read([&](auto&& v){
  std::cout << v << '\n';
});
```

for an `int` with synchronized access.

I'd advise against having `synchronized(synchronized const&)`.  It is rarely needed.

If you need `synchronized(synchronized const&)`, I'd be tempted to replace `T t;` with `std::aligned_storage`, allowing manual placement construction, and do manual destruction.  That allows proper lifetime management.

Barring that, we could copy the source `T`, then read from it:

```
synchronized(synchronized const& o):
  t(o.read(
    [](T const&o){return o;})
  )
{}
synchronized(synchronized && o):
  t(std::move(o).read(
    [](T&&o){return std::move(o);})
  )
{}
```

for assignment:

```
synchronized& operator=(synchronized const& o) {
  access([](T& lhs, T const& rhs){
    lhs = rhs;
  }, *this, o);
  return *this;
}
synchronized& operator=(synchronized && o) {
  access([](T& lhs, T&& rhs){
    lhs = std::move(rhs);
  }, *this, std::move(o));
  return *this;
}
friend void swap(synchronized& lhs, synchronized& rhs) {
  access([](T& lhs, T& rhs){
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs, rhs);
  }, *this, o);
}
```

the placement and aligned storage versions are a bit messier.  Most access to `t` would be replaced by a member function `T&t()` and `T const&t()const`, except at construction where you'd have to jump through some hoops.

By making `synchronized` a wrapper instead of part of the class, all we have to ensure is that the class internally respects `const` as being multiple-reader, and write it in a single-threaded manner.

In the **rare** cases we need a synchronized instance, we jump through hoops like the above.

Apologies for any typos in the above.  There are probably some.

A side benefit to the above is that n-ary arbitrary operations on `synchronized` objects (of the same type) work together, without having to hard-code it before hand.  Add in a friend declaration and n-ary `synchronized` objects of multiple types might work together.  I might have to move `access` out of being an inline friend to deal with overload conficts in that case.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/600be274cda69f77)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there must be something wrong with your design if you want to move an object containing a mutex.

But if you decide to do it anyway, you have to create a new mutex in move constructor, that is e.g:

```
// movable
struct B{};

class A {
    B b;
    std::mutex m;
public:
    A(A&& a)
        : b(std::move(a.b))
        // m is default-initialized.
    {
    }
};
```

This is thread-safe, because the move constructor can safely assume that its argument isn't used anywhere else, so the locking of the argument isn't required.

Comment: Why would it necessarily be bad design to have a movable type that contains a mutex? I don't see why it would be a bad idea to move-return a thread-safe object from a factory function. Moving a thread-safe object to a vector also seems fine to me.

Comment: "*the argument isn't used anywhere else*" - what is the reasoning for this?

Comment: That is not thread safe. What if the `a.mutex` is locked,: You loose that state. -1

Comment: @DieterLücking As long as the argument is the only reference to the moved-from object, there is no sane reason for its mutex to be locked. And even if it is, there's no reason for locking a mutex of a newly created object. And if there is, this is an argument for overall bad design of movable objects with mutexes.

Comment: @AntonSavin Even worse, you will introduce multiple unrelated mutexes protecting the same thing.

Comment: @DieterLücking This is just not true. Can you provide a code illustrating the problem? And not in the form `A a; A a2(std::move(a)); do some stuff with a`.

Comment: @AntonSavin Your move constructor is doing it (creating multiple mutexes).

Comment: @DieterLücking I'm with Anton on this one. To move from an object you better be the ONLY person who is accessing it - this includes having a lock on its internal mutex. You can create a new mutex in the new instance as nobody has a reference to the moved from one anymore and so they're using the new instance along with the new mutex.

Comment: @DieterLücking the mutex of moved-from object is protecting nothing after the move constructor execution. And the moved-from object is going to be imminently destroyed. So how exactly the creation of a new mutex introduces any thread-unsafety?

Comment: However, if this were the best way I would recommend anyway `new`-ing up the instance and placing it in a `std::unique_ptr` - that seems cleaner and isn't likely to lead to issues of confusion. Good question.

Comment: @MikeVine I think you should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using mutexes and C++ move semantics is an excellent way to safely and efficiently transfer data between threads.

Imagine a 'producer' thread that makes batches of strings and provides them to (one or more) consumers. Those batches could be represented by an object containing (potentially large) `std::vector<std::string>` objects.
We absolutely want to 'move' the internal state of those vectors into their consumers without unnecessary duplication.

You simply recognize the mutex as part of the object not part of the object's state. That is, you don't want to move the mutex.

What locking you need depends on your algorithm or how generalized your objects are and what range of uses you permit.

If you only ever move from a shared state 'producer' object to a thread-local 'consuming' object you might be OK to only lock the moved **from** object.

If it's a more general design you will need to lock both. In such a case you need to then consider dead-locking.

If that is a potential issue then use `std::lock()` to acquire locks on both mutexes in a deadlock free way.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock

As a final note you need to make sure you understand the move semantics.
Recall that the moved from object is left in a valid but unknown state.
It's entirely possible that a thread not performing the move has a valid reason to attempt access the moved from object when it may find that valid but unknown state.

Again my producer is just banging out strings and the consumer is taking away the whole load. In that case every time the producer tries to add to the vector it may find the vector non-empty or empty.

In short if the potential concurrent access to the moved from object amounts to a write it's likely to be OK. If it amounts to a read then think about why it's OK to read an arbitrary state.