# std::map of non-movable objects

Tags: c++11, std, stdmap, moveabletype

Related to my previous question: [Inserting an object having a non copyable field into an std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049854/inserting-an-object-having-a-non-copyable-field-into-an-stdvector)

It seems that I can have a map storing non-movable objects `A` *only* if `A` is default constructable.

**Is there any way in C++11 to have a map store `A` if `A` is not default-constructable and non-movable?**

```
#include <mutex>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public:
     A(int i) {}

  private:
    std::mutex m;
};


int main() {
    std::map<int, A> m;
    //m.emplace(1, 3); //A is not movable => does wouldn't compile.
}
```

Comment: `A` doesn't even need to be default-constructable, if you avoid using `operator[]`.

Comment: `m[0]` requires `A` to be default-constructible because it is specified to default-construct a value if one does not yet exist for that key.

Comment: You should use `m.emplace(1);` instead of `m.emplace(1, A{});`. Not sure if that second one is even valid. Anyway, the first one _actually_ inserts the element in place.

Comment: @ aschepler How would you insert A into the map without using the index operator?

Comment: @– YoYoYonnY Thanks for your comment. I am not sure if my question is clear, but A is not movable.

Comment: @user695652 `m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(1), std::forward_as_tuple());`

Comment: @user695652 I'm not sure if my method is correct, looking at a reference manual the arguments to emplace will be used to construct a pair, not just an element. Daniel's method might work.

Comment: @user695652 The problem with your usage of `m.emplace(1, A{})`; is that it constructs `A` (Using `A{}`) _before_ it is inserted into the `std::map`. You would have to pass the `emplace` arguments such that it constructs `A` in-place. Daniels method might do that.

Comment: With the edited question, if I uncomment `m.emplace(1, 3);` it does compile for me.  (This would fall under http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair case (3).)

Comment: @DanielSchepler   I get an  error: use of deleted function 'A::A(const A&)'

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I've compiled it using gcc 6.2.0.

Comment: I see, it's a C++14 feature, I'm using gcc 4.8.2 wiht --std=c++11 flag (can't use 14)

Comment: Hmm... logging into an Ubuntu 14.04 machine with gcc 4.8.4, I can indeed reproduce the compiler or standard library bug.  But `m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(1), std::forward_as_tuple(3))` does compile there as well to work around the bug.

Comment: Oh, also, I think if the `A(int)` constructor were `explicit` then the `piecewise_construct` version would still be needed - the cppreference documentation says pair constructor (3) only participates in overload if the arguments are implicitly convertible to the corresponding pair elements.

Comment: @ Daniel Schepler thanks this worked. But why are you calling this behavior a bug of gcc, std11?