# std::mutex as class member, and store class obect to container

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

Below is minimal code to reproduce the error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

class A {
    std::mutex mutex;
    public:
    A(){};
};
int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string,A>> aa;
    A a;
    //aa.push_back(std::make_pair(std::string("aa"),A()));
    //aa.push_back(std::make_pair(std::string("aa"),a));
    aa.push_back(std::make_pair(std::string("aa"),std::move(a)));    
}
```

Below is error.

> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27026.1 for x64
>     Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xlocale(319):
> warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are
> not enabled. Specify /EHsc    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\utility(405):
> error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer
> list' to '_Mypair'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\utility(405):
> note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor
> overload resolution was ambiguous
>   ..\examples\json_object\json.cpp(16): note: see reference to function
> template instantiation 'std::pair<std::string,A>
> std::make_pair<std::string,A>(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&)' being compiled            with
>           [
>               _Ty1=std::string,
>               _Ty2=A          ]
```

Similar error for `gcc` compiler. 
When I remove `std::mutex` from class OR don't push the object on `std::vector`, then it compiles fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by P.W and hint provided by freakish I come up with below solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class A {
    std::mutex mutex;
    public:
    A(){};
};
int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::shared_ptr<A>>> aa;
    A a;
    //aa.push_back(std::make_pair(std::string("aa"),A()));
    //aa.push_back(std::make_pair(std::string("aa"),a));
    aa.push_back(std::make_pair(std::string("aa"),std::make_shared<A>()));   
}
```

I modified my container to store smart pointer of object instead of object itself.

Comment: FWIW, you should really use `std::unique_ptr` unless you *really* need shared ownership.  90% of the time, you don't.

Answer (score 11):

As per the documentation on [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex).

> `std::mutex` is neither copyable **nor movable**.

Since class `A` contains a `std::mutex` variable `mutex`, it is not movable either.

Comment: The way to overcome this is to use (smart) pointers to std::mutex.

Answer (score 5):

As P.W. pointed out, `std::mutex` is neither copyable nor movable, and for good reason.  The whole point of having a mutex is to protect against simultaneous multithreaded access to some data.  The move operation itself needs to be protected, and the mutex should be ***used*** by the move operation.

The following example gives the class some movable data and shows how the mutex should be used in a move operation (copy operations would be similar):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
  A() {};

  // Move constructor
  A(A&& other) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(other.m_mutex);
    m_data = std::move(other.m_data);
  }

  // Move operator
  A& operator=(A&& other) {
    if (this == &other) return *this;

    // Lock this and other in a consistent order to prevent deadlock
    std::mutex* first;
    std::mutex* second;
    if (this < &other) {
      first = &this->m_mutex;
      second = &other.m_mutex;
    } else {
      first = &other.m_mutex;
      second = &this->m_mutex;
    }
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard1(*first);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard2(*second);

    // Now both this and other are safe to access.  Do the actual data move.
    m_data = std::move(other.m_data);
    return *this;
  }

private:
  std::mutex m_mutex;
  std::unique_ptr<int> m_data;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string,A>> aa;
  A a1;
  A a2;
  a1 = std::move(a2);
  aa.emplace_back("aa", std::move(a1));
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. This answer by Howard Hinnant shows a simpler way to avoid deadlock using `std::unique_lock`, `std::defer_lock` and `std::lock`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29988626/1047213

Comment: @Hari Thanks for that link.  std::lock() prevents the deadlock and is a much better solution than manually coding in that logic.