# Cannot push_back/create object with mutex member on to vector due to copy deleted

Tags: c++, mutex

I have a `std::vector<S>`, where struct `S` contains many data members, including a mutex. Some of these members are initialized by the constructor.

I have created a self-contained example below, where I create and add to the vector once the constructor values are available:

```
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

struct S
{
    S() = default;

    S(int a, double b, char c) : a_(a), b_(b), c_(c){}

    std::mutex mutex_;
    int a_;
    double b_;
    char c_;
    // + Many more class members
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> vec;

    // Later when constructor arguments are known
    vec.push_back(S(6, 6.7, 'f'));
}
```

However, because one of the members is a `std::mutex` I cannot perform the assignment:

```
<source>:19:16: note: copy assignment operator of 'S' is implicitly deleted because field 'mutex_' has a deleted copy assignment operator
```

I understand the basics why this error exists- you can't copy a mutex.

I'd prefer not having to write a copy constructor because I have a lot of class members and it seems overkill just to allow mutex to be copyable.

Are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: Just `emplace_back` your object

Comment: A `std::unique_ptr<std::mutex>` can be moved inside a `std::vector`.

Comment: @Dmitry that [would not fix this error](https://godbolt.org/z/zTW7GPEaf).

Comment: You will need to explicitly make your type movable. Because std::mutex is neither movable nor copyable, this is a bit tricky. You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986208/how-should-i-deal-with-mutexes-in-movable-types-in-c for guidance.

Comment: @DrewDormann yeah, I forgot about reallocations

Comment: @rare77 do you need the vector to be resized later or do you just need a dynamically sized (but not resizable) array?